# How to create a search statment in java with multiple optional where clauses?

Tags: java, mysql, database

Following is the code for a general search:

```
     int row = jTable_accounts.getSelectedRow();
    String Table = (jTable_accounts.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
      String sql ="select c.customer_id as 'Customer No.', customer_name as 'Name',a.account_id as 'Account No.',DIA,a.balance as 'Current Balance',a.outstanding_amt as'Outstanding Amt.' from customer c inner join customer_details cd on cd.customer_id=c.customer_id inner join account a on a.customer_id=c.customer_id where a.account_id= '"+Table+"' ";
```

So the result will be shown in a jtable,however, I would like to add 4 or 5 text boxes which should filter the result according to customer name, outstanding amount or etc. These text boxes should be optional entries and if the user does not enter any value to any of the textboxes the application should show the general output (the above code).

I assume there should be some where clauses added into the select statement but i am not sure how it should be optional.

These are the three tables for further information:

customer:

```
     customer_id     DIA     customer_name             birth_date    
     --------------  ------  ------------------------  ------------- 
     1               32       Ahmad mohammad bin afif  (null)        
     2               10       mohammad ahmad bin afif   (null)
```

customer_details:

```
     customer_id     phone_no1     phone_no2     address_line1     address_line2    
     --------------  ------------  ------------  ----------------  ---------------- 
     1               0111231415    019123443     bukit             (null)           
     2               01345532      (null)        kl                serdang
```

account:

```
    account_id     balance     outstanding_amt     customer_id    
    -------------  ----------  ------------------  -------------- 
    1              12530.23    1821.3              1              
    2              2040.13     125.3               1              
    3              213455      1234.3              2
```

Comment: Obligatory SQL injection humor link triggered by first code snippet: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: What's the question exactly? How to write SQL? How to detect checkbox states? How to do string concatenation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check if the textboxes trimmed values are not empty and then, if not, you can build your extra filters in your query.

e.g.

```
if (textField1.getValue().trim().length > 0) {
  query += " and COLUMN1 = " + textField1.getValue().trim() + " ";
}
if (textField2.getValue().trim().length > 0) {
  query += " and COLUMN2 = " + textField2.getValue().trim() + " ";
}
```

.
   .
   .

since you have a basic query where you state a "where" statement, you only have to check if the textfields are empty in order to add "and" statements.

Comment: Thanks @Apostolos ,however, this will work if you already have a where clause and it will keep adding "AND" (which in my case it will work) but could also share with me how would you do it if you don't have any where clause in the statement at all?

Comment: quick n dirty solution: replace inner join and use table1,table2 where table1.column1=table2.column2 in order to join these tables. so here is your where :)

Comment: lol true that thanks a lot, your ideas were indeed really useful. Anyhow if someday you found out other solutions such as an array with a special condition or anything else please share it with me.

Comment: i use hibernate actually, so i initiate Criteria object and place my filters there with the conditions i mentioned above. hibernate then will construct my query without me having to worry about build the query ;)